# Парсер страниц вконтакте

Tags: php, парсер

Доброго всем времени суток господа

Собственно, есть код:

```
$ch = curl_init (); 
curl_setopt ($ch , CURLOPT_URL , "http://vk.com/id111"); //копируем HTML код страницы
curl_setopt ($ch , CURLOPT_USERAGENT , "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; ru-RU; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050919 Firefox/1.0.7"); //типа мы делаем это из мозиллы
curl_setopt ($ch , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , 1 ); 
$content = curl_exec($ch); //Записываем награбленное в $content
echo "".$content."";
```

Если подставить страницу обычного смертного сайта - все супер, подставляю контакт - идет загрузка страницы и все. Подскажите, как спарсить всю, интересующую страницу с этого заколдованного сайта и запихать ее в переменную?

p.s. гуголь мучал уже долго, что то там глухо на эту тему. музыка, ссылки, прочая дребедень, все что угодно, только не оригинальный и полный код страницы. Очень интересует та, часть в которой отображается где пользователь online или нет

Comment: Хм, а что в переменной `$content`?

Comment: @VladD - дык, дело в том, что до нее просто не доходит! Данный код просто не может считать страницу. С другими сайтами без проблем (с которыми я пробовал). С контактом какая то фигня

Comment: @mixalef, используя ваш же код скачал вашу же страницу. Не вижу проблемы. Только вот кодировка неправильная. Написали бы, чего такого хотите там откопать - может оно в API есть, а вы не знаете.

Comment: мм.. Здорово. В коде вообще ничего не заменяли? (Видимо, что то у меня, буду пробовать этот же код на других хостингах) А как при парсинге еще кодировку поменять?

Comment: @mixalef, 

iconv("windows-1251","utf-8", $content);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Зачем, если есть открытый `API`?
https://api.vkontakte.ru/method/getProfiles?uids=111&fields=online

Comment: Не подходит, т.к. мне нужен код в оригинале, а его больше чем в информации API. И кстати по указанной ссылке НЕВЕРНАЯ информация. Там написано online. Реально на той странице человека уже неделю нету! Так что API не вариант

Comment: бессмысленно парсить страницы сайтов на постоянной основе, т.к. они не обещают что будут показывать  всё одинаково. Api хотя-бы обещает документировать изменения. А в вашем случае вы будете парсер писать раз в 2-3 месяца заново.

Comment: @mixalef, так написано же ``online:0``, т.е. offline.

Comment: @eicto - не хочу никого грузить, но именно эта неодинаковость и нужна! буду очень признателен, если напишите как спарсить весь HTML код.

@xEdelweiss - неа! там написано -> заходила 5 июня в 16:01

.. уважаемые, разве нет способа спарсить 1 страницу, с указанным id с контакта? Мне казалось это как то просто

Comment: @mixalef дело в том, что вы наверное не понимаете "неодинаковость" неодинаковость может быть совсем неодинаковостью, другие id, другие элементы, js  данные, **сейчас** online от offline отличается наличием `display: none` у элемента с id 'ofile_online_lv'

Comment: да блиин, я не php проггер, но вот тебе тривиально все

<?php

$vid=111;

        $url = 'https://api.vkontakte.ru/method/getProfiles?uids=' . $vid . '&fields=online';
        $ch=curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $r=curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $arr = json_decode($r,true);
        $current_state=$arr['response']['0']['online'];

        echo $current_state;
?>

где выведет тебе 0, если офлайн или 1 если онлайн

Comment: @alister, более того, если добавить поле ``last_seen``, то можно узнать и когда последний раз заходил человек, но автор, видимо, хочет расковырять там что-то секретное :)

Comment: а я просто когда-то писал робота шпиона, неплохо так API поюзал :)

Comment: @alister - спасибо, но, как догадался @xEdelweiss у меня действительно кое что крайне неадекватное и секретное. Сам знаю, что то, что вы все написали нужнее в большинстве случаев, просто если бы это было так, я бы сам уже это применил.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте грузить страницу другими методами, например когда-то я так делал:

```
$content = file_get_contents("http://vk.com/id111");
```

В любом случае если вы будете часто парсить странички, вас будут блокировать капчей :)

Comment: @IVsevolod - я настолько форевер алон, что даже капча меня не любит! Серьезно