# Авторизация в vk.com для полноценного доступа к страницам

Tags: php, вконтакте, vkontakte-api, curl

Доброго всем времени суток господа

[Немного похоже на эту тему, но все же не то](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/228301/php-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86-%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5)

С контакта можно спарсить ПОЛНЫЙ `html` код страницы, чему я здесь научился и благодарен. Но вконтакте есть пользователи, страницы которых доступны только для пользователей этого сайта, и соответственно нужно как то авторизоваться, перед тем как парсить страницу (а нужно именно всю страницу, а не отдельные данные).

Может ли кто привести пример кода, как, запуская (в моем случае кроном) простую `php` страницу авторизваться в контакте, для последующих действий?

Comment: если так нельзя, или кто то пробовал и не получилось - напишите. нет - тоже ответ

Comment: все можно, просто почитайте про php curl, часть про POST и куки. Но мне больно смотреть как вы удаляете гланды, когда есть нормальный способ делать всё то что вы делаете. (а ещё я вам скажу, что ваша затея ничем хорошим не кончится irl)

Comment: @eicto - ну согласитесь, что было бы что то элементарное - не спросил бы. Ну хоть какой то ответ, хотя ждал большего

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понял вам нужно авторизоваться в Вконтакте.

Попробуйте вот так, но я не уверен.

```
 <?php
        function login($mail, $pass){       
        $ch = curl_init("https://login.vk.com/?act=login&email=$mail&pass=$pass");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
            $authoriz = curl_exec ($ch);
            curl_close($ch);

            if(!preg_match('/remixsid=([a-f0-9]{32})/', $authoriz, $sid))
                    die('Bad login/pass');
            else
                    return "remixchk=5;".$sid[0];
    }
    login("Логин", "Пароль"); 
    ?>
```

Comment: оно самое, после этого можно парсить все, что надо. спс